# CakePHP - página com uso de mais de uma table

Tags: php, cakephp

Eu tenho uma dúvida, sobre salvar dados no banco de dados usando CakePHP, quando precisa manipular com mais de uma tabela.
Eu estou criando um sistema de cadastro de clientes e nele tem um um sistema para cadastrar login's e senhas do cliente, como painel de controle, banco de dados, etc.

***A estrutura do banco de dados***

**Clientes**

Tem os campos com os dados do cliente, como telefone, email, etc

**opcoes**

> - id
> - opcao (nome da opção, como painel de controle, banco de dados, etc)
> - usuario_ativ (campo para indicar se tal opção vai ter preenchimento de usuário)
> - host_ativ (campo para indicar se tem o host/ip, como banco de dados... painel de controle não teria esta opção

**rel_op_cliente**

> - id_cliente
> - id_opcao
> - senha
> - host
> - usuario

Eu consegui resolver a questão de no formulário aparecer os dados, no controller de cliente eu coloquei `public $uses = array('Cliente','Opcao', 'RelInfoCliente');` e com isso ele consegue capturar os dados das 3 tabelas... mas no caso de salvar os dados do form, qual seria a melhor forma que ao salvar o cliente salve os dados das opções, se eu alterar o nome de usuário alterar na tabela `rel_op_cliente`

Comment: qual a relação entre essas tabelas?

Comment: clientes seria tipo a tabela pai, o rel_op_cliente relaciona com o clientes. Tabela clientes tem o campo id e rel_op_clientes tem o id_cliente, as duas ligam dessa forma. A tabela opcoes liga com o rel_op_cliente por meio do id_opcao. Não sei se expliquei claro, mas resumindo, rel_op_clientes é onde fica armazenado os dados e opcoes seria o nome desses dados, como painel de controle, banco de dados e teria também o campo de ativar ou desativar alguns campos (na exibição), como painel de controle que não é necessário aparecer o ip, é só usuário e senha

Comment: Eu não entendi direito. Mas me parece que você não estabeleceu uma relação (hasMany, hasOne, etc...) entre elas, estabeleceu?
Se não, você deve repensar suas tabelas e models e fazer o link entre elas corretamente. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma pesquisada nessa questão.
O esquema seria simples, rel_op_cliente liga com cliente, opcoes liga com o rel_op_cliente... mas vou analisar melhor, que parece ser a melhor solução para o problema de linkar, e iria ser do modo correto do que eu fiz

Comment: Eu acho que você tem uma relção de `hasMany`ou `hasMany trought` da uma olhada e estabeleça essa relação usando a conveção correta do cakephp. Vai ficar muito mais facil de trabalhar

Comment: Valeu cara, já tinha feito com hasMany e ficou bem melhor que a solução que fiz de array( 'joins'... etc.... No caso, teria um pai, filho e neto, a associação, vou dar uma olhada nesta questão de relação hasMany trought.... Para exibição parece perfeito, depois vou ver se para salvar segue a mesma ideia

Comment: Bem, eu ainda estou quebrando um pouco a cabeça, do cliente ligando com a tabela rel_op_cliente está perfeito, agora esse rel_op_cliente teria que ser ligado com o opcoes... usei o hasmany em cliente e em rel_op_cliente coloquei, mas quando dou um vardump não aparece as informações da tabela opcoes, como se não estivesse fazendo a ligação, o opcoes seria como uma classe neto. Cliente liga com o rel_op_cliente que liga com o opcoes. Essa parte que não estou conseguindo resolver

Comment: Para que o cakephp funcione corretamente você tem que usar as suas conveções. Sua tabela `rel_op_cliente` não segue a conveção de nome de tabela do cakephp. Explique um pouco mais sobre o que pretende fazer e qual a função dessas tabelas na sua pergunta que te ajudo a relaciona-las.

Comment: Bem, colocando a estrutura | 

**Clientes**

id = 3

nome = Braulio


**rel_op_clientes**

id_cliente = 3

id_opcao = 2

senha = 123

usuario = braulio_holtz

host = 192.168.0.1

**opcoes**

id = 2

opcao = Banco de dados mysql

usuario_ativ = 1

host_ativ = 1

| Seria mais ou menos esse esquema que estaria, acho que dá para compreender um pouco, em clientes fica os clientes, em rel_op_clientes fica a relação clientes e opções, em opções fica os nomes dos campos que entra o usuário e senha, tipo, painel de controle, banco de dados, etc

Comment: Cara, então é isso mesmo. Você tem uma relação onde `Usuarios HABTM Opcoes`. Você deve olhar a opção `HABTM`no link que te passei e nomear a tabela de acordo com o que está lá!!

Comment: Mas e o caso da tabela rel_op_clientes? o Opcoes seria tipo mostrar o nome do campo, por exemplo, lá teria o id e o nome, onde o nome seria por exemplo, Painel de controle, banco de dados, etc, basicamente esta tabela seria apenas mostrar qual é o campo escolhido, evitando ter que a cada cadastro de clientes colocar as mesmas coisas (como painel de controle que todas as hospedagens tem)... Não é uma tabela de usuários para logar no sistema, é uma tabela com registros de dados dos clientes de login's e senhas para múltiplos serviços (Paineis de controle, banco de dados, etc)

Comment: Exatamente. A tabela de usuarios podem ter as informaçoes que você quiser e voce deve criar uma terceira tabela `opcoes_usuarios` onde irá conter `user_id` e `option_id` assim você pode relacionar varios usuarios com varias opcoes. Leia sobre o `HABTM`

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido a questão

```
public  $hasAndBelongsToMany  =  array (
    'opcoes_clientes'  =>  array (
        'className'  =>  'opcoes' ,
        'joinTable' => 'rel_infos_clientes',
        'foreignKey'  =>  'id_cliente' ,
        'associationForeignKey'  => 'id_opcao',
        'dependent'  =>  true
    )
);
```

No caso só estou mudando o nome da tabela para ficar dentro da convenção, mas agora entendi. joinTable seria a tabela intermediária e em classname seria a classe com a tabela "neto"...

Comment: que bom que conseguiu, cara! =)

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, mudei para a convenção, ficou melhor ainda, dai não precisei colocar joinTable, ForeignKey, AssociationForeignKey